# how does Argothian Enchantress interact with Sasaya, Orochi Ascendant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If [Sasaya, Orochi Ascendant](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=87595) successfully transforms would [Argothian Enchantress](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=5686)'s ability kick into effect during that transformation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not interact. When you flip Sasaya, you are not casting it. To cast a spell has a specific meaning, which is to place a spell on the stack and perform all the necessary steps including paying for it, etc. Flipping Sasaya happens as a result of using its activated ability, no spell casting is taking place.

Note that also when you first cast Sasaya, it does not trigger the Argothian's ability, because it is not an enchantment at that time:

> 709.2. In every zone other than the battlefield, and also on the battlefield before the permanent flips, a flip card has only the normal characteristics of the card. Once a permanent is flipped, its normal name, text box, type line, power, and toughness don’t apply and the alternative versions of those characteristics apply instead.

Answer (score 4):

- Was a spell cast? No, self-evidently. Then "Whenever you cast an [x] spell" triggers won't trigger.
- Did a new permanent enter the battlefield? No: an existing permanent changed its characteristics. So "Whenever an [x] enters the battlefield" triggers won't trigger, either.

Comment: And I doubt there's any triggers for "Whenever a permanent becomes an [x]" :)